# Adding marker tags to specific portion of text in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

The ultimate goal of this feature is to allow users select placeholders in message templates(variable names are text between %). [The dribbble motivation](https://dribbble.com/shots/15663512-Mass-Email-Send/attachments/7457915?mode=media)
The api returns strings in the format below.

"Hello %First_Name% %Middle_Name% %Last_Name%,Per the staff attendance records in %Message_Title%, the following cars have not been sold today %Day%:%Employee_Name% should investigate why is no record."

As of now I replace the % with  opening and closing tags. I use a contenteditable div to display this as depicted in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKOKF.png). I want the user to be able to click on the tags eg.First Name Middle_Name etc. to add the placeholder to any point of the text and remove existing marker tags.
I would like to know:

- alternatives on how to
- alternatives on displaying html in user input fields
- I would like to know how to find the cursor position in contenteditable div to allow a user to add a place holder by click on any tag.
- How to remove whole html tags (opening and closing tags and all content inbetween them.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you are looking for `contenteditable="true"` attribute. this attribute allow user to edit content without additional codding. and you can get the text content with `innerText` property

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#getContent');
button.onclick = ()=>{
  let textContent = document.querySelector('.content').innerText;
  console.log(textContent);
}
```

```css
.editable{
  padding: 0.25rem 0rem;
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<p class="content">Hello <span class="editable" contenteditable="true"> First Name</span> <span class="editable" contenteditable="true">Last Name</span>, Per the ............................</p>
<button id="getContent">Get content</button>
```

Comment: All parts of the text should be editable and still add highlights to specific text. I used the contenteditable="true" on the main content div

Comment: i thought you only wanted to edit those highlighted text. glad my answer helped you 